# Displaying messages to tty using whiptail through monit

Tags: shell, whiptail, monit

I would like to display a [`whiptail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/whiptail.1.html) message on the login screen that is triggered by `monit`, but I am without luck.

I understand it might be something to do with interactive/non-interactive shell. Here is the script that gets triggered by `monit`.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/whiptail --infobox 'Hello World.' 7 25 >/dev/tty1
```

Is there a trick, or should I avoid using whiptail?

Comment: Does the `--infobox` option work for you from just a regular shell? I just tried it and it doesn't do anything, `--msgbox` works though.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following and was able to send output from my desktop to `/dev/tty2` using `whiptail` so I think what you're doing would seem feasible. Couple of things that I noticed.

#### 1. permissions

I needed to be root in order to send anything to `/dev/tty2`. I'm assuming you're running this as a `monit` user who would most likely not have permissions to send data to and tty device.

#### 2. `--infobox`

The `--infobox` switch didn't appear to work in my current shell but I was able to send an `--infobox` to `/dev/tty2`. YMMV. `--msgbox` worked in both cases.

Comment: I can send `echo 'Hello World.' >/dev/tty1` using monit, so it is not permissions. Also, `--infobox` will dismiss itself without waiting for user input, but the display will remain if you send it from another console.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is that whiptail (like dialog) writes its messages by default to the *standard error*, because conventional program use the *standard output* for screen updates.

You can redirect the standard error by putting a `2` next to the `>` mark:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/whiptail --infobox 'Hello World.' 7 25 2>/dev/tty1
```

Further reading:

- [**`whiptail`** - *display dialog boxes from shell scripts*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail)
- [*How to use **whiptail** to write interactive shell scripts*](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-use-whiptail-to-write-interactive-shell-scripts/)
- [**`dialog`** - *display dialog boxes from shell scripts*](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html)